# How to post data to the same ejs view or partial after using res.render get?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, ejs

I need to display data that gets posted after rendering view with res.render() in get. When I use <% date %> my view throws an error saying that date is not defined and I know this happens because my value does not exist before rendering the view and its getting set after. So how do I set this variable to be displayed in my ejs file **before or after** my view gets rendered?

I have tried a few things like using res.send(), using another get() inside my post() and even creating a partial view but nothing works. **I dont want to click any buttons to be able to do this** and if its only possible with clicking well then. I know **you cant use res.send() on the same view twice**.

My post XMLHttpRequest is executed when the page loads in javascript to set my date variable and send it to my node.js file then I use express to fetch it. My node.js code is the following:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.render('index', {
        time: time,
        views: visitors,
        mobileViews: mobileVisitors,
    });
}

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('working');

    getInfo = req.body;

    console.log(getInfo);

    //getInfo.date = 1

    res.render('index', {dataTest: getInfo.date}); //this doesnt work

    //OR res.send({dataTest: getInfo.date}); doesnt work

    //OR app.get('/', function (req, res) {res.render ... doesnt work
}
```

My ejs view is:

```
<h1 class="test">test <%= dataTest %></h1>
```

My js file:

```
var waitForEl = function (selector, callback) {
    if (jQuery(selector).length) {
        callback();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            waitForEl(selector, callback);
        }, 100);
    }
};

waitForEl(".daterangepicker", function () {

    var element = document.querySelector('.ranges ul').childNodes[0].childNodes[0].data.toString();

    console.log(element);

    var date = 0;
    date = sendData(date, element);

    var obj = JSON.stringify({date: date});

    console.log(obj);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:4000", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    xhr.send(obj);
});

function sendData(date, element) {


    if(element == 'Today') {

        date = 1;
    }

    return date;
}
```

Comment: Let me get this straight, you're using an Ajax request that sends a `post` request to `app.post("/", handler)` and you're expecting to render an index template with the data that you just submitted?

Comment: @goto1 Yeah I am using Ajax post request to send my date variable to the app.post("/", handler) and getting the value with req.body. I need that value (getInfo.date) to be seen in my view before or after rendering my view, if possible without clicking

Comment: That's not possible with your current approach. If you want to render the `index` template with some data that you submit with `Ajax` you need to persist this information in a session and/or database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
const bodyParser =require('body-parser');
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.render('index', {
        time: time,
        Views: visitors,
        mobileViews: mobileVisitors,
    });
}

app.post('/',urlencodedParser,function(req, res){
    console.log('working');

    getInfo = req.body;

    console.log(getInfo);

    res.render('index', {getInfo: getInfo});

}
```

you need also a midlleware to handle post method in express app

```
npm i body-parser
```

it's better to use the object's key name as its value name to ease cycling through the properties

then in your ejs view use :

```
<%= getInfo.date %>
```

there is an **=** sign,don't forget it.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is the first time you are trying to get "/" you don't have a`getInfo.date`

So make a `getInfo.date = Date.now()`

Or `getInfo.date = new Date()`

And pass it in into your initial get('/') call.

`const bodyParser =require('body-parser');
const urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }); 
app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.render('index', { time: time, Views: visitors, mobileViews: mobileVisitors, getinfo: getInfo}); }
app.post('/',urlencodedParser,function(req, res){ console.log('working'); 
getInfo = req.body; console.log(getInfo); res.render('index', {getInfo: getInfo}); }`.

> on the other hand you may also choose to make the `getInfo.date = null` or `getInfo.date = ''`

And check in your ejs with if condition `if(getinfo.date){<=getinfo.date>}`

> Trying from mobile. Hope this solves